Unable to understand a proof of the squeeze theorem
In the book I'm reading (Apostol's Calculus Vol. 1), the author gives a proof of the squeeze theorem, right after teaching about the basic limit properties (limit of a sum property, limit of a difference property, etc). I'm struggling to understand a part of the proof.
This is how he states the squeeze theorem:
Suppose that $f(x) \le g(x) \le h(x)$ for all $ x \ne p$ in some neighbourhood $N(p)$. Suppose also that $\lim_{x\to p} f(x) = \lim_{x\to p} h(x) = a$.
Then we also have $\lim_{x\to p} g(x) = a$.
His proof goes as follows:

Let $G(x) = g(x) - f(x)$. Let $H(x) = h(x) - f(x)$. The inequalities $f \le g \le h$ imply $0 \le G(x) \le H(x)$ for all $x \ne p$ in $N(p)$.
To prove the theorem, it suffices to show that $\lim_{x \to p} G(x) = 0$, given that $\lim_{x \to p} H(x) = 0$.

And then in the next few steps he shows that $\lim_{x \to p} G(x) = 0$.
The part of the proof I am unable to understand is step 2, where he states that $\lim_{x\to p} G(x) = 0$ implies the squeeze theorem.
Suppose it's true that $\lim_{x\to p} G(x) = 0$.
My guess is that the author wants us to use the following reasoning: By definition of $G$ we have $\lim [g(x) - f(x)] = 0$. Then, using the limit of a difference property, we have that $\lim_{x\to p} g(x) - \lim_{x\to p} f(x) = 0$, and hence that $\lim_{x\to p} g(x) = 0$, since $\lim_{x\to p} f(x) = 0$.
The issue I have with this argument is that I feel like the limit of a difference property cannot be used here, because we don't know beforehand that $\lim_{x \to p} g(x)$ exists (we are trying to prove that it exists and that it equals $a$). Thus we cannot say that $\lim_{x\to p}[g(x) - f(x)] = 0 \implies \lim_{x\to p} g(x) - \lim_{x\to p} f(x)$, and the proof falls apart.
What am I misunderstanding?

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to p} g(x) &= \lim_{x\to p} (f(x) + g(x) - f(x))
\\ &= \lim_{x\to p}(f(x) + (g(x) - f(x)) 
\\ &= \lim_{x\to p}(f(x) + G(x))
\\ &= \lim_{x\to p} f(x) + \lim_{x\to p} (G(x))
\\ &= \lim_{x\to p} f(x) + 0.
\end{align}$$
The first three lines should be obvious, since I did nothing but rewrite the internal expression, i.e. I used the fact that for all $x$, we have $g(x)=f(x)+G(x)$.
The important inequality goes from line 3 to line 4, where we split the limit into two. There, I used the fact that both of these limits exist. We know that the first exist because that is the assumption of the theorem, and we know the second exists because that's just the limit of $G$ and its existence has already been shown.

So I guess I just didn't apply the limit properties as cleverly as I could've. Thanks.

@MahdiRkioui I guess. It's a very common trick that if you know something about $A$, and something about $A-B$ (and therefore about $B-A$), then when analyzing $B$, you use either $A=B+(A-B)$ or $B=A+(B-A)$. Don't worry too much about not thinking of it this time, with practice it will become second nature.

It's only “obvious” once you've seen it!

I would like to focus on your issue with the argument where you say that we can only use the addition and subtraction rules for limits if we know that both summands do have a limit. At first glance, this is true. But it's also true if we know that one summand and the sum have a limit.
Let's say $f(x)$ has a limit at $p$, and $h(x):=f(x)+g(x)$ does, too. Then $g(x)$ also has a limit at $p$ because $g(x)=h(x)-f(x)$, and we can now apply the limit law for differences, since both $h$ and $f$ converge.
And that's what happens in Apostol's proof, too. We know $f(x)$ converges, and we prove that $G(x)$ converges. Then since $g(x)=G(x)+f(x)$, we get convergence of $g(x)$ (and to the sum of the limits of $G$ and $f$).

Yes, this is the idea that 5xum used in their answer. It seems simple in retrospect but I think it would've taken a long while for me to figure it out on my own. I appreciate the explanation.

You're assuming that the limits of $f$ and $h$ exist.
Once you show that the limit of $G$ exists, you can note that
$$
g(x)=G(x)+f(x)
$$
and from the existence of the limits of $G$ and $f$ you can deduce the existence of the limit of $g$ and also that
$$
\lim_{x\to p}g(x)=\lim_{x\to p}G(x)+\lim_{x\to p}f(x)
$$
In this case the limit of $G$ is zero and you're done.
More generally, the same trick allows you to say that if
$$
h(x)=f(x)+g(x)
$$
and that any two of the limits
$$
\lim_{x\to p}f(x)\qquad \lim_{x\to p}g(x) \qquad \lim_{x\to p}h(x)
$$
exist finite, then so does the third and
$$
\lim_{x\to p}h(x)=\lim_{x\to p}f(x) + \lim_{x\to p}g(x)
$$
